# Weak independence of gaussian distribution given a constraint on samples

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

Suppose samples $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ in space $G$
follow a (multivariate) gaussian (normal) distribution
with specified mean and variance, 
i.e., $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n \overset{i.i.d}{\sim} f_X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$,
where $f_X$ means corresponding probability density function, 
and $\mu,\Sigma$ are known.
The cardinality of $G$ is $\#G=n$.
Now we partition $G$ into subspaces $G_1$ and $G_2$,
namely, $G=G_1\bigoplus G_2$.
We suppose $\#G_1=s$ and $s\ll n$.
Next we construct 
$$
\widetilde{x}\overset{\mbox{def}}{=}x^{jk}=x_j-x_k,\quad j,k\in G_1
$$
and let $K=\{\widetilde{x}\}$. 
Then we easily have that $\widetilde{x}$ is 
normal (it is the linear combination of $x$ restricted on $G_1$)
and $\#K = s^2$.
We assume that points of $\widetilde{x}$ are very sparse in
the whole space $G$ (the condition $s\ll n$ can also guarantee this).
In particular, WLOG, we set $n=20000$ and $s=10$.
We investigate the **independence** between $\widetilde{X}$ and $X$.
Intuitively and theoretically, 
$\widetilde{X}$ and $X$ are not independent, 
since they are correlated by noting that $G_1\subset G$
(independence and correlation are 
equivalent for normal variables).
Let $C=\mbox{Cov}(\widetilde{X},X)$.
By the construction as well as the
sparsity assumption of $\widetilde{x}$, 
we have that $C$ is nearly a zero matrix, 
which means *$\widetilde{X}$ and $X$* 
are somewhat (maybe) **weak independence**.
In addition, the simulation studies
on assumption *$\widetilde{X}$ and $X$ are independent*
works well (since then
we have $f(\widetilde{x},x)=f_{\widetilde{X}}(\widetilde{x})f_X(x)$).
However, I still cannot convince myself 
without literature support (papers or books).

Another construction on $G=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n\}$ given as 
$$
\breve{x}\overset{\mbox{def}}{=}x_i,\quad i\in H,
$$
where $H=\{x\in G: \mbox{mean}(x)=1\}$.
Then we also want to check 
the *independence between $\breve{X}$ and $X$*.
This time we have a help 
link to [Hint](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/302920/),
but I cannot fully understand the discussion there.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your question is?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity @JeremyC. My question are two aspects:
(1) can we treat **$\widetilde{X}$ and $X$ is independent**?
(2) can we treat **$\breve{X}$ and $X$ is independent**?

Comment: Your terminology is difficult to decipher, because you seem to conflate *dimension* with *cardinality* and *vectors* with *indexes.*  Could you perhaps supply a small illustrative example to communicate the setting to us?